# Quiz game with timer

Tags: beginner, go, concurrency, timer, quiz

This is my first Go program. I would like to know what could be improved, what is done wrong, and anything else that I should know. The CSV contains 10 questions with the 10 answers separated by a comma. For example:

```
10+10,20
4+5,32
```

If you want the full context this is from [gophercises](https://gophercises.com/exercises/quiz) which are some exercises to practice Go.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)


var points int

func main() {
    fPtr := flag.String("csv", "problems.csv", "FileName in csv (question, answer)")
    tPtr := flag.Int("time", 10, "Time in seconds")
    sPtr := flag.Bool("shuffle", true, "shuffle your questions order")
    flag.Parse()
    questions := readCSV(*fPtr)

    fmt.Print("Press enter to start you have ", *tPtr, " seconds")
    fmt.Scanln()

    askQuestions(&questions, *tPtr, *sPtr)

    fmt.Println("You got ", points, " points")
}

func askQuestions(questions *[][]string, time int, s bool) {

    go startTimer(time)
    for _, i := range shuffle(s, len(*questions)) {
        fmt.Println("Question ", (*questions)[i][0], ":")
        var a string
        fmt.Scan(&a)
        a = strings.ToLower(strings.Trim(a, " "))
        if a == (*questions)[i][1] {
            points++
        }
    }
}

func shuffle(shuffle bool, sliceLen int) []int {
    var r []int
    for i := 0; i < sliceLen; i++ {
        r = append(r, i)
    }
    if shuffle {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
        rand.Shuffle(len(r), func(i, j int) {
            r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
        })
    }

    return r
}

func readCSV(s string) (questions [][]string) {
    f, err1 := os.Open(s)
    records, err2 := csv.NewReader(f).ReadAll()
    for err1 != nil || err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err1, err2)
        fmt.Println("Please re-enter the name of the CSV file: ")
        fmt.Scan(&s)
        f, err1 = os.Open(s)
        records, err2 = csv.NewReader(f).ReadAll()
    }
    return records
}

func startTimer(seconds int) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Time is up! You got ", points, " points")
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the exercises resource! Looks nice and useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `startTimer()`

The `time` package provides timers natively. So rather than using a call to `time.Sleep()`, you can use [`time.NewTimer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTimer).

Use `fmt.Printf()` rather than `fmt.Println()` for printing formatted strings.

```
func startTimer(seconds int) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Time is up! You got ", points, " points")
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Becomes:

```
func startTimer(sec int) {
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(sec) * time.Second)
    <-timer.C
    fmt.Printf("Time is up! You got %d points\n", points)
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

### `readCSV()`

In `readCSV()`, you have multiple error variables. You can instead use a single error variable as you go along.

I advise against adding file retry logic. It complicates the code, and most users can simply re-run the command upon error. Instead, you should return an error value.

Using a named return (`questions`) means you should actually use the `questions` variable. Because I switch to multiple return values, I removed the named parameter.

Also be sure to close the file after you're done reading from it.

```
func readCSV(s string) (questions [][]string) {
    f, err1 := os.Open(s)
    records, err2 := csv.NewReader(f).ReadAll()
    for err1 != nil || err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err1, err2)
        fmt.Println("Please re-enter the name of the CSV file: ")
        fmt.Scan(&s)
        f, err1 = os.Open(s)
        records, err2 = csv.NewReader(f).ReadAll()
    }
    return records
}
```

Becomes:

```
func readCSV(name string) ([][]string, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(name)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    qs, err := csv.NewReader(f).ReadAll()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return qs, f.Close()
}
```

### `askQuestions()`

Again, here you should use `fmt.Printf()` to print formatted strings.  You also use the value `i` as an index, but with the `range` keyword you can access the currently indexed value, see [here](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16).

You should check the return of `fmt.Scan()`.

Rather than starting the timer within `askQuestions()`, I opted to move it to `main()`. This means we can remove the `time` argument.

### `main()`

Naming variables like `fPtr` and `sPtr` is just extra typing. Documenting the type in the name itself is not very useful.

- `fPtr` becomes `name`
- `tPtr` becomes `time`
- `sPtr` becomes `shuffle`

**From your updated code with shuffling:**

Rather than keeping a second copy of the shuffled questions, just modify the array in-place. You also don't need to seed `rand` (see [this example](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Shuffle) from the Go docs).

### Conclusion

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"
)

var points int

func main() {
    name := flag.String("csv", "problems.csv",
        "filename in csv (question, answer)")
    time := flag.Int("time", 10, "time in seconds")
    shuffle := flag.Bool("shuffle", true, "shuffle your question order")

    flag.Parse()

    questions, err := readCSV(*name)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if *shuffle {
        rand.Shuffle(len(questions), func(i, j int) {
            questions[i], questions[j] = questions[j], questions[i]
        })
    }

    go startTimer(*time)

    if err := askQuestions(&questions); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("You got %d points\n", points)
}

func readCSV(name string) ([][]string, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(name)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    qs, err := csv.NewReader(f).ReadAll()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return qs, f.Close()
}

func askQuestions(questions *[][]string) error {
    for i, q := range *questions {
        fmt.Printf("Question %d: %s\n", i+1, q[0])

        var a string
        _, err := fmt.Scan(&a)

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if a == q[1] {
            points++
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func startTimer(sec int) {
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(sec) * time.Second)
    <-timer.C
    fmt.Printf("\nTime is up! You got %d points\n", points)
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Added some notes about your updated shuffling code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will make the changes. for the range loop in `askQuestions` I chose `i` not to make a copy, wouldn't it be faster? Also do you know any go exercise to practice with go concurrency routines channels?

Comment: @lucarlig The performance difference will be negligible, so I would prefer the most readable code. One resource is the Go [tour of concurrency](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1). You can read and page through with live code examples.